# Couchbase: MetaData.Metrics always contain default values?

Tags: couchbase

I am testing Couchbase, and I am making a very simply query:

```
    public async Task SelectRandomJobs(int nbr)
    {
        IBucket bucket = await cluster.BucketAsync("myBucket");
        IScope scope = bucket.Scope("myScope");

        IQueryResult<JObject> result = await scope.QueryAsync<JObject>("SELECT * FROM myCollection WHERE Id = {id}");

        // The Metrics.* has default values
        Console.WriteLine(result.MetaData.Metrics.ElaspedTime);
    }
```

Here are the values:

[image]

I was expecting ElaspedTime (misspelled!) and ExecutionTime to be not null. There is a AnalyticsQueryAsync method, but that did work for me ([error 24045](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/analytics/error-codes.html)).

Why are those values null?

-- UPDATE --

I followed the advice of Eric, but I got the same results:

[image]

Comment: Looks like they have consistently misspelled that field in several versions.

Comment: You will need to enable metrics on that query, we will provide an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

So you will need to enable Metrics for this query, I have provided a code sample below with two possible ways of doing this, it is covered in our docs but maybe could be easier to find or have better examples, this is something I will investigate further and see if we can make it clearer in future editions of the docs.

I have used the `travel-sample` dataset and tried to set the code up similar to your example so that it will be easy to implement for you.

As for why the times are null by default and the other fields are zero, that seems to just be a design decision for this class.

About the misspelling, we have filed a ticket to get the spelling corrected. Thank you for pointing that out.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Couchbase;
using Couchbase.Query;
namespace _3x_simple
{
  class Program
  {
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
      var cluster = await Cluster.ConnectAsync("couchbase://localhost", "Administrator", "password");
      var bucket = await cluster.BucketAsync("travel-sample");
      var myScope = bucket.Scope("inventory");
      //scope path
      var options = new QueryOptions().Metrics(true);
      var queryResult = await myScope.QueryAsync<dynamic>("SELECT * FROM airline LIMIT 10;", options);
      //cluster path
      //var queryResult = await cluster.QueryAsync<dynamic>("SELECT * FROM `travel-sample`.inventory.airline LIMIT 10;", options => options.Metrics(true));
      Console.WriteLine($"Execution time before read: {queryResult.MetaData.Metrics.ExecutionTime}");
      await foreach(var row in queryResult){
          Console.WriteLine(row);
      }
      Console.WriteLine($"Execution time after read: {queryResult.MetaData.Metrics.ExecutionTime}");
      Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
      Console.Read();
    }
  }
}
```

You won't see the execution time until after the results are read. The reason you are seeing default values for those fields is because you are trying to read that information at the wrong time/place considering your async operation.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, I will check this shortly! Also, I will post another question, that I posted in the Couchbase forums, but it doesnt seem to get past quaranteen there =)

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65001938/couchbase-benchmark-insert-and-get-using-keyvalue-operations-are-very-slow-s

Comment: So, u can add QueryOptions to Scope and Cluster, but not collection? There are numerous situation like these, and I don't understand why the Collection doesnt allow for same methods as in scope or cluster?

Comment: I updated my answer, the QueryOptions approach didnt seem to work.